Spring Oauth2 Authorization server - Login, registration and forget passowrd flows along with social login
I went through Spring Oauth2 authorization server tutuorials on spring offical website and I have following question, for which I didnt get a concrete answer
Requirement: Login, Registration & forget password along with Social Login in respective client.
i.e., web or ReactAPP (IOS or Andriod)
Problem:
With OAuth2 authorization server. It would be similar to social login where client is redirected to authroization server hosted web pages for login (Do we need to custom implement the registation and forget password flows in authorization server, if we stick to authorization server)

if we have to use API based approach for login from respective client web or APP (I think most of the websites does this) where UI is hosted on respective client itself, Does it break the oauth2/openId connect standards. If API is possible, How to do the same in Spring security authorization server?

How all the websites are using their own custom login/registation/forget password pages in front end itself? are they not concerned about the security?
I implemented the authorization server with social login also. But not able to seperate login from authorization server
Also I am confused on registration and forget passord flows

You are asking about "Spring security authorization server".
Implementing the OAuth2 standard is can be a good way. To achieve that, refer to the Spring Authorization Server ( https://spring.io/projects/spring-authorization-server ) site.
And I have implemented it here. You can check the source code.
https://github.com/patternknife/spring-security-oauth2-password-jpa-implementation
